# NativeScript Sidekick iOS Code Signing Error: Auto Generation Failed

Tags: ios, nativescript, sidekick

I am trying to use "iOS Auto Generate Provisioning Profile and Certificate" inside SideKick. The first time I set up the Provisioning and Certificates with that it worked. But the provision expired so I tried to set up this thing again but i got this error:

```
Auto Generation Failed
An error has occured while generating the certificate and mobile provision. Reason: expecting an array or an iterable object but got [object Null].
```

I use a free, new created Apple ID for this purpose. Is there a way to avoid this failure?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a change on Apple side, that leads to an error in the generation of certificate and mobile provision. The team is working on this issue, you can follow its progress here: https://github.com/NativeScript/sidekick-feedback/issues/435